# Partial Page update using jQuery to show image and delete images on confirmation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to partially update page when i upload or delete the image.

What i want is that when ever i browse.. to upload images i should automatically be able to refresh the images section after image upload is complete and also refresh the image section when i delete the image.

Please advice how it can be done and if possible with a complete code example..

or if some on can provide me with jQuery ASP.Net based control that will upload and show images also into the folder and database and give me option to delete the image later also all should be possible with partial page update as i have other control on the page

Comment: This is not very difficult. What have you done so far? We are not going to write this for you. If you don't want to script this yourself, I suggest looking for already existing systems. There are plenty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want asyc file upload check [jqUploader](http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/), here is triger for upload complete